# Can I put my jest mock in a separate file? manual mock

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, mocking

In my `get-sites.spec.js` I created a mock like this which works perfectly fine:

```
jest.mock('@aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager', () => {
    const SecretsManagerClient = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
        const result = {
            SecretString: "{\"server\":\"host\",\"database\":\"database\",\"user\":\"userName\",\"password\":\"password\"}"
        };

        return {
            send: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(result)
        };
    });

    const GetSecretValueCommand = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
        return {}
    });

    return {
        SecretsManagerClient,
        GetSecretValueCommand
    }
});
```

I've tried creating the following directory structure and moved the mock code to the `client-secrets-manager.js` file.

```
__tests__/
|- get-sites.spec.js
__mocks__/
|- @aws-sdk/
|-- client-secrets-manager.js
src/
|- get-sites.js
```

Then in my `get-sites.spec.js` file I changed the mock code to `jest.mock('@aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager');`

When I run the test I get an error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'SecretString')`. Is there some way to move my mock to a separate file to make it available to all my unit tests that will preserve the functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was close. I changed the `client-secrets-manager.js` file in the **mocks** folder to look like this:

```
const SecretsManagerClient = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return {
        send: jest.fn()
    };
});

const GetSecretValueCommand = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return {}
});

module.exports = {
    SecretsManagerClient,
    GetSecretValueCommand
}
```

Then in my `get-sites.spec.js` file I added this line to the test:

```
const sendResponse = {
    SecretString: "{\"server\":\"host\",\"database\":\"database\",\"user\":\"userName\",\"password\":\"password\"}"
};
jest.spyOn(SecretsManagerClient.prototype, 'send').mockResolvedValue(sendResponse);
```

Then I was able to assert it was called like this:

```
expect(SecretsManagerClient).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
expect(SecretsManagerClient.prototype.send.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1);
```